# Formula.recalculateFormulas producing gack

Tags: apex, formula-field, gack, winter20

Winter 20 release is in live, so I wanted to use this glorious feature [Formula.recalculateFormulas](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Formula.htm#apex_class_System_Formula)

Thus I tried the below block of code:

```
Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(Purchase_Price__c=2000 , StageName='Underwriting' ,Acquisition_Channel__c ='Direct to Consumer');
List<FormulaRecalcResult> frc =Formula.recalculateFormulas(new List<Opportunity>{opp});
System.debug(frc);
```

To my surprise, the below piece of code produces gack

> Error on line 10, column 1: System.UnexpectedException: Salesforce
>   System Error: 1845503703-144759 (548651819) (548651819)
>   Class.System.Formula.recalculateFormulas: line 10, column 1

Whereas the standard SObject [recalculateFormulas](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) works

```
Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(Purchase_Price__c=2000 , StageName='Underwriting' ,Acquisition_Channel__c ='Direct to Consumer' );
opp.recalculateFormulas();    
System.debug(opp.Total_Finance_Amount__c); //Prints 2000
```

The doc doesn't say that this is beta, has anyone faced this issue and managed to fix it?

Comment: any cross-object formulas?

Comment: @cropredy yes a lot of.... it’s a 200column table with 10+ cross object formulas

Comment: try adding the relationship fields in the first example and see what happens. The sobject version of `recalculateFormulas` blew up if relationship fields existed; perhaps `Formula` is the opposite?

Comment: @cropredy that might be it... I have raised a case to confirm this.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal was this ever confirmed as a fix? I'm getting the same error now.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Any confirmation on this one, plz ?